# How can I create a create a java regular expression for a comma separator list

Tags: java

How can I create a java regular expression for a comma separator list

(3)
(3,6)
(3 , 6 )

I tried, but it does not match anything:

```
Pattern.compile("\\(\\S[,]+\\)")
```

and how can I get the value "3" or "3"and "6"  in my code from the Matcher class?

Comment: Sorry, can you clarify for me - how exactly is this list stored/input? Are you talking about a literal string like you have above: "(3)" or "(3,6)" or "(3 ,6)", or are the brackets merely meant as seperators? It would be helpful if you could provide Java code showing you trying to match an example.

It's possible you will be able to do something far simpler depending on how these lists are stored/input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Validation regex

You can try this meta-regex approach for clarity:

```
    String pattern = 
        "< part (?: , part )* >"
            .replace("<", "\\(")
            .replace(">", "\\)")
            .replace(" ", "\\s*")
            .replace("part", "[^\\s*(,)]++");

    System.out.println(pattern);
    /*** this is the pattern
    \(\s*[^\s*(,)]+\s*(?:\s*,\s*[^\s*(,)]+\s*)*\s*\)
    ****/
```

The `part` pattern is `[^\s(,)]+`, i.e. one or more of anything but whitespace, brackets and comma. This construct is called the *negated character class*. `[aeiou]` matches any of the 5 vowel letters; `[^aeiou]` matches everything but (which includes consonants but also numbers, symbols, whitespaces).

The `+` repetition is also made possessive to `++` for optimization. The `(?:...)` construct is a non-capturing group, also for optimization.

#### References

- [regular-expressions.info/Character Class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), [Possessive Quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html), [Non-capturing Group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)
- [`java.util.regex.Pattern`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

---

#### Testing and splitting

We can then test the pattern as follows:

```
    String[] tests = {
        "(1,3,6)",
        "(x,y!,a+b=c)",
        "( 1,    3  , 6)",
        "(1,3,6,)",
        "(())",
        "(,)",
        "()",
        "(oh, my, god)",
        "(oh,,my,,god)",
        "([],<>)",
        "(  !!  ,  ??  ,  ++  )",
    };

    for (String test : tests) {
        if (test.matches(pattern)) {
            String[] parts = test
                .replaceAll("^\\(\\s*|\\s*\\)$", "")
                .split("\\s*,\\s*");

            System.out.printf("%s = %s%n",
                test,
                java.util.Arrays.toString(parts)
            );
        } else {
            System.out.println(test + " no match");
        }
    }
```

This prints:

```
(1,3,6) = [1, 3, 6]
(x,y!,a+b=c) = [x, y!, a+b=c]
( 1,    3  , 6) = [1, 3, 6]
(1,3,6,) no match
(()) no match
(,) no match
() no match
(oh, my, god) = [oh, my, god]
(oh,,my,,god) no match
([],<>) = [[], <>]
(  !!  ,  ??  ,  ++  ) = [!!, ??, ++]
```

This uses `String.split` to get a `String[]` of all the parts after trimming the brackets out.

Comment: I tried "\\(\\S+(,\\S+)*\\)". But (1,3,6,) should fail, but it did not.

Comment: @michael: sorry, my mistake. Check latest revision.

Comment: I understanding what you meant by 'That is, some opening bracket, then one part, then zero-or-more part preceded by the delimiter, then the closing bracket.' But in "\\([^\\s,]+(,[^\\s,]+)*\\)" why there are 3 ','? it should be only 1, right?

Comment: @michael: the commas inside the `[...]` construct is part of the character class definition. It's negated, since it's `[^...]`. Overall the character class matches "anything but whitespace and comma".

Comment: Thank you.  I have slightly modified the regular expression to \\(([^,]+)(,[^,]+)*\\).  But how can I get the value out? E.g. if my input is (1,3,6), I want to parse out "1", "3", "6". And if my input is (1), I want to parse out "1".  I tried m.groupCount();, it always returns me "2"

Comment: @michael: ok, sorry for going all over the place with my answer (need sleep). Check my latest revision and see if it does what you need. I'll get back to this tomorrow after I get some sleep.

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear to me exactly what your input looks like, but I doubt the pattern your using is what you want.  Your pattern will match a literal `(`, followed by a single non-whitespace character, followed by one or more commas, followed by a literal `)`.

If you want to match a number, optionally followed by a comma and another number, all surrounded by parentheses, you could try this pattern:

```
"\\(\\s*(\\d+)\\s*(,\\d+)?\\s*\\)"
```

That should match `(3)`, `( 3 )`, `( 3, 6)`, etc. but **not** `(a)` or `(3, a)`.

You can retrieve the matched digit(s) using `Matcher.group`; the first digit will be group `1`, the second (if any) will be group `2`.